# String Value of ID returns more than ID

Tags: apex, visualforce, urlhacking, string

I have a visualforce page that I pass a related Event's id to the url to reference.
I want to then push it into a field.

the resulting UR of the page is for example:

```
/apex/NewTripMeetingEntry?EventId=00U7A000001jiu3
```

B/c it is an Event and I can't look up to it, I need to pass the ID as a string to my text field.
Here's my code:

```
EventIdString = String.valueOf( [select id from Event where Id=: (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId'))]);


        TM = new Trip_meeting__c ();
        TM.Meeting__c=EventIdString;
```

It collects the string but also returns extra text including the (Event:{Id= so that it puts in the text field as:

> (Event:{Id=00U7A000001jiu3UAA}

What about string.Valueof am I missing here?
thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're calling `String.valueOf()` on the Event Sobject itself, not the Id string.  As written, your first line should be:

```
EventIdString = String.valueOf( [select id from Event where Id=: (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId'))].Id);
```

But you don't even need to use `String.valueOf()`. ID can be directly cast to String:

```
EventIdString = (String)[select id from Event where Id=: (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId'))].Id;
```

And even that is superfluous! If your variable is already a string, you can simply:

```
EventIdString = [select id from Event where Id=: (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId'))].Id;
```

Because IDs are strings. Or...you know:

```
EventIdString = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId');
```

Works just fine too.

Comment: Option: '[Query].Id' is not safe. If no matching record found it will through System.QueryException

Comment: OK, then how about displaying the subject?  Eventreference= [select subject from Event where Id=: (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId'))].Id; is showing me the ID not the subject...

Comment: That's because you're still getting the Id at the end. You'd need to replace ".Id;" with ".Subject;"

Answer (score 9):

Technically, since you're passing the value as a String already, you probably don't need to query the value at all:

```
TM.Meeting__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId');
```

However, say you wanted to validate the value first, to make sure the user can see it (so they're not just faking a value), you could do this:

```
String eventId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId');
if([SELECT COUNT() FROM Event WHERE Id = :eventId] == 1) {
    TM.Meeting__c = Id.valueOf(eventId);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you should just be doing the following:

```
TM.Meeting__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId');
```

As Christian mentioned, your current code is trying to perform `String.valueOf` on the result of a SOQL query, which would be an SObject.  Unlike SQL, if you query a single column/field and expect to get one result, you *cannot* assume you will just get a simple String back.  You have to save the result to the appropriate SObject type and then you can parse out the fields you specified in your SOQL query.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic can be optimized in a better way but here's a possible solutions for what you have

```
//you also need to make sure that the EventID in the param is not empty or this will break
Event tempE = [select id from Event where Id=: (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('EventId'))];
EventIdString = tempE.Id;


        TM = new Trip_meeting__c ();
        TM.Meeting__c=EventIdString;
```

Also I am not quiet sure why you don't save the page param directly in the `TM.Meeting__c` field?